# Appcelerator Titanium: Is it possible to access the user's music?

Tags: iphone, media, appcelerator

With Appcelerator Titanium is there any method for accessing the user's music library?

With the Apple SDK I can implement the MPMediaPickerController, which allows the user to create a playlist of media items for use in a third party app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now available in the upcoming 1.4 with the `Titanium.Media.openMusicLibrary`, `Titanium.Media.hideMusicLibrary` and `Titanium.Media.systemMusicPlayer` APIs.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I know you guys must be super busy right now.  Great work on the new version.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any systemMusicPlayer or openMusicLbirary in 1.4
http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.4/Titanium.Media-module

Perhaps it got punted to 1.5?